# Inspector displays different rotation than script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to read out the X rotation of my camera.

The Inspector tells me "Rotation X = 10".

I would like to retrieve this value by code.
Therefore I added a script to my player gameobject and assigned the camera as "camera".

Then I used this code:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("RotX World: " + camera.transform.rotation.x.ToString());
    Debug.Log("RotX Local: " + camera.transform.localRotation.x.ToString());
```

This resulted in the value "0.08715578" instead of "10" (which is displayed by the Inspector).

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I have to use eulerAngles like this, not camera.transform.rotation.

The correct way to store the rotation would be in a Vector3 like this:

```
_CameraRot = new Vector3(camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```

I wonder if what the Inspector shows under "Rotation" are actually the eulerAngles?

Comment: `camera.transform.rotation` is a [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) and not Euler. The values displayed in the inspector are the Euler Angles (a `Vector3`).